# Spring boot YAML autocomplete support in Intellij Community Edition

Tags: spring, spring-boot, intellij-idea, intellij-14, intellij-plugin

I am using intellij for building spring boot application and i am facing issues in autocomplete in yml files using intellij community edition?

Is there any plugin available for the intellij autocomplete for the yml files

Comment: Search for Intellij or in the marketplace.
[Spring Initializr and Assistant](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/18622-spring-initializr-and-assistant)

Answer (score 7):

Try this [Spring Assistant](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/10229-spring-assistant) idea plugin

Answer (score 1):

Autocomplete is not natively supported by IntelliJ for Spring Boot YAML configuration files.

There is an open issue for this:

- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-151708

There is no IntelliJ plugin supporting autocomplete for Spring Boot YAML configuration either.

Comment: install pluggins for : lombok, spring, spring assistant; turn on annotation processor, rebuild your project (and modules) to get new *metadata.json

Comment: You also need to add <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
   <optional>true</optional>
  </dependency> to your pom.xml

Answer (score 0):

There is a plugin for IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition which might be very helpful with autocomplete and a few more things, here is it's the website: [Spring Boot Assistant](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/17747-spring-boot-assistant).

You can get the plugin from the link above or directly from the IDE:

1. File & rarr; Settings (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> on Windows).
2. Search for "Plugins".
3. Go to Marketplace.
4. Search for "Spring Boot Assistant".
5. Install it and restart your IDE.

Answer (score 0):

Install  Spring Boot Helper plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Install Spring Boot Assistant IntelliJ Plugin.